# Unexpected token < reading xml file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I'm having a problem when i do an ajax call.

My code is :

```
$('#regLink').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  urlLink = $('#regLink').attr('name') + $('input[name="email"]').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    url: urlLink,
    success: function (xml) {
      var code = $(xml).find('int').text();
      if(code == '1') {
        console.log('email gravado com sucesso');
      }
      else {
        console.log('algo correu mal');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

The call give this response :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<int xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">1</int>
```

And it give me this error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

The URL points to another site, so its a cross domain call.

I just want to read the "1" and give a success alert.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JavaScript says to make an Ajax request using the JSONP pattern (which involves inserting a `<script src="something">` element into the document instead of using XMLHttpRequest).

The response you are getting is an XML document, not a JavaScript program following the JSONP pattern, which would be something like:

```
value_of_query_string_callback_argument({ "int": 1 });
```

You get the error because the browser is trying to execute the XML as JavaScript (which it isn't).

Either change the response to be JSONP, or use [some other method to make a cross-domain request](/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy).