# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in chrome app

Tags: xml, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to load an XML file in a chrome packaged app and keep getting the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < index.html:1"

The XML file is local in the app and am loading it using javascript.  The error is related to the loading of the XML file as when I remove the first "<" from the file it changes the error to the next character.

The file is being loaded simply with var documentURL = "file.xml"; and is followed with a function which uses the file.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: You get the error because the browser is trying to execute the XML as JavaScript (which it isn't). See the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934187/unexpected-token-reading-xml-file

Comment: @gui47 You should flag this as a duplicate.